# Twitch IRC stops sending messages after random amount of time

Tags: python, irc, twitch

I have a problem that my bot just keeps giving empty lines after a random amount of time which renders the bot useless
i made a log and it just keeps giving me INFO:root: after the random amount of time.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
con = socket.socket()

con.connect((HOST, PORT))


send_pass(PASS)
send_nick(NICK)
con.send(bytes('CAP REQ :twitch.tv/tags\r\n', 'UTF-8'))
join_channel(CHAN)

data = ""
while True:
    try:
        ready = select.select([con], [], [], 8)
        if ready[0]:
            data = con.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
            print(data)
            logging.basicConfig(filename='crash.log', level = logging.DEBUG)
            logging.info(data)
            if len(data) != 0:
                data_split = re.split(r"[~\r\n+]", data)
                data = data_split.pop()
```

If you need any more info please say so

Comment: Please provide the code **in** the question, using a code block. Also try to provide a standalone code as small as possible so it is easier for us to help.

Comment: What are the last values of `data` before it becomes empty?

Comment: sorry how do i do code blocks?

Comment: The last values depends,
sometimes it's after a ping and sometimes it's just after someone typing something, it's just really random and it can take 5 min to do it or 20 min

Comment: Could you add the code in the question by editting it? It's unreadable on a single line.

Comment: Now it's done ! ^^

Comment: What happens if you use `logging.info(repr(data))` instead?

Comment: gonna test that right now it might take 10-20 min for it to go blank again

Comment: now it's like this:
INFO:root:':tmi.twitch.tv 001 evilbot254 :Welcome, GLHF!\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 002 evilbot254 :Your host is tmi.twitch.tv\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 003 evilbot254 :This server is rather new\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 004 evilbot254 :-\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 375 evilbot254 :-\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 372 evilbot254 :You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.\r\n:tmi.twitch.tv 376 evilbot254 :>\r\n'

Comment: I meant around the time you start getting empty messages.

Comment: i now get this INFO:root:' '
first i only had INFO:root:

Comment: So there is a space between the two single quotes?

Comment: with the ' ' there is a space between it yes

Comment: So it means Twitch is sending you these spaces, and nothing else. I guess that's another bug in Twitch's server (it's far from being the only one I heard of).

Comment: is that fixable or not, since i'm pretty sure it's not for every bot

Comment: Also it started happening randomly
first it worked fine but now it keeps giving me spaces